# Json is only used in android programming to read data from the database right?

Tags: android, json

I'm confused as to when Json is needed to be used in android programming. I have read a couple of tutorials but I'm still blur as to why we need Json and when to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Json is just a format to store data, like XML, you can use it to store whatever you want or don't use it at all. However in terms of database access the thing is that *natively* Android can only access local SQLite databases, which are not suitable for projects that require a centralized database that change dynamically (and is accessed from many devices concurrently), so in that cases the most popular solution is to setup a [JSON-RPC Server](http://json-rpc.org/) which will act as intermediary between the Android app and the database.

From the app you will remotely call a method on the server which will execute the query and return the appropriate results.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, while JSON format may be used for database operations (as it can be used as a serialisation mechanism for your model objects), the area where you will use it the most is web communication. Most modern web APIs use JSON as a response data format.

As for working with JSON data, consider using `org.json` library, which is natively included in Android SDK and really easy to use.

As for what JSON is, the full name makes things easier - *JavaScript Object Notation*. So, basically, it is a way to turn an Object into a String, to enable transferring it between systems.

Answer (score 1):

**Json** is used every where, not just in android.

It is a light-weight format that is used for data interchanging over the network.
Mostly when writing web-services Json is used instead of XML becuse it is much more lightweight as compared to XML.

You can read more about the why to use json instead of xml, here
http://www.sitepoint.com/json-vs-xml/

Answer (score 1):

JSON isn't always needed. But a lot of people prefer it.

As usual there are multiple ways to get the end-result. 
JSON is one of these, and it is pretty simple!

It is a easy way to share data, a lot of sites are using JSON. Think at some news-sites or blogs with a title, date and time stamp, and the actual message('s). Easy to read and implement in an android application.

```
[
    {
        "Title": "First Message",
        "Date": "01-10-2015",
        "Time": "18:00",
        "Post": "This is one message."
    },
    {
        "Title": "SecondMessage",
        "Date": "01-10-2015",
        "Time": "18:30",
        "Post": "This is the second message."
    }
]
```

But you also could get data from an database with a php-script, and load it into applications.